# R: Fixed heatmap scale across datasets

Tags: r, heatmap

I am plotting a heatmap (map population density values) of a given administrative region for different years: 2005, 2008, 2011, and 2014. I want to have a color scale that is normalized across all datasets. That is, if the population density values are increasing across years, I want to see this visually. The heatmap colors are usually normalized within a dataset. For example,

**2005**: area1: 0.433, area2: 0.677, area3: 0.091, area4: 0.123

**2008**: area1: 0.532, area2: 0.701, area3: 0.111, area4: 0.222

**2011**: area1: 0.643, area2: 0.711, area3: 0.190, area4: 0.298

**2014**: area1: 0.711, area2: 0.820, area3: 0.211, area4: 0.450

For my actual data, each year has 81 values that range from 0.1 to .75.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably go with a facet, assuming you don't care too much about the exact arrangement of your plots. You can follow this example:

```
library(ggplot2)
data("french_fries")
ggplot(french_fries, aes(y=subject, x = treatment)) +
geom_tile(aes(fill=potato)) +
facet_grid(~time)
```